# Print file data during a for loop

Tags: python, shutil, os.path

I have to propose this question again, I'm a newbie in `Python` and I can't resolve this.

I'm trying to print the filename and the filesize during this for loop when the file is moved to the new folder. I know the `os.path.getsize(path)` and `os.stat(path).st_size` methods, but which path can I enter if my file change every loop?
This code hasn't errors, but I don't know how to print the data during the loop as the file change.

```
src = ("C:\\..\\files")
dest1 = ("C:\\..\\files\\images")
files = os.listdir(src)   #files is a list of files in a folder

for file in files:
    if file.endswith(".jpg") or file.endswith(".png") or file.endswith(".jpeg"):
        if not os.path.exists(dest1):
            os.mkdir(dest1)
        shutil.move(src + "/" + file, dest1) #for every file that is moved I have to print filesize and filename.
        #print(??)
```

Comment: Your question is unclear please consider rephrasing based on https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Hi there and welcome! Please check out https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example and prefer focusing on one question at a time. Also check out `pathlib.Path` for convenient Path operations. On cleaner code/refactoring, try to do "one thing" at time, you have several things going on there in the for loop.

Comment: Did you get an actual error message? If so it would be useful to add it to your question. Also try posting a more minimal example of the problem, it doesn't have to be your actual code but a shorter example that demonstrates the issue. One approach I may suggest is to split the code into two loops: one to build a list of (original file -> renamed file) pairs (maybe a dict or a list of tuples?), and another to do the actual moving. After that works, look into converting the 1st loop (that builds a dict from some input data) into a dict comprehension / list comprehension. Just a thought.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IIUC, try:

```
src = ("C:/Users/username/")

with open("recap.csv", "w") as recap_file:
    csv_writer = csv.writer(recap_file, delimiter="\t")
    
    for file in os.listdir(src):
        if file.endswith(".jpg") or file.endswith(".png") or file.endswith(".jpeg"):
            dest = f"{src}/images"
        elif file.endswith(".odt") or file.endswith(".txt"):
            dest = f"{src}/docs"
        elif file.endswith(".mp3"):
            dest = f"{src}/audios"
        else:
            continue        
        size = os.path.getsize(f"{src}/{file}")
        print(f"File name: {src}/{file}; Size: {size}")
        csv_writer.writerow([f"{src}/{file}", size])
        if not os.path.exists(dest):
            os.mkdir(dest)
        shutil.move(f"{src}/{file}", dest)
```

Answer (score 0):

Moving the file should generally not change the file size [1], so you can check the file's size before performing the move.

On the other hand, since you know where you move the file, you could also determine files size after the move. Moving a file from `src + "/" + file` to `dest1` means that the file should be at `dest1 + "/" + file` after the operation[2]. You can use this to not only print the new path of the file, but also determine the file's size at the new location.

[1] (NB: file size *can* change when moving from one file system to another, with different block sizes and size specified as a multiple of the block size. However, this should not be a problem for this case.)

[2] Moving the file could fail for a number of reasons (file was deleted intermittently, there is already a (write-protected) file with that name at the destination, no space left in destination, ...). You should add some error handling for such cases, e.g. with a `try ... except` block around the `shutil.move` operation.

Comment: If i try to print (os.path.getsize(dest1 + "/" + file)), I have an error: can only concatenate str (not "int") to str.